# How to upgrade cordova 2.2.0 in Dreamweaver CS5.5?

Tags: cordova, upgrade, dreamweaver

What are the steps to be followed to upgrade cordova 2.2.0 in Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Dreamweaver, but the upgrade path is probably the same as it is for Eclipse: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_upgrading_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Guides